# Vue3 Child Emits not firing in parent (Composition)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm new to vue and trying to learn how events work between Children and parents.

I have created a child component which exposes an emit in the script setup:

```
const emit = defineEmits(['OnTileClicked'])

function TileClicked() 
{
    {{counter.value++}}
    console.log( props.tileId + " Tile clicked in Child component");
    emit('OnTileClicked');
}
```

This gets called and I can see the message in the console.

I the parent I have the following in my template

```
<CheckerBoardTile width= 100% id="1" tileId="tile1" @OnTileClicked()="TileClicked('Tile1')"/>
```

and the following in the script setup

```
const totalClickCount = ref(100);

function TileClicked(name) 
{
  totalClickCount.value++; 
  console.log(name + ' Clicked Detected Total:' + totalClickCount.value);
}
```

But this does not get called.

Thanks for helping

Darran

```
Would expect parent function to be called when child event is fired
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but your syntax for handler is a bit wrong.

Try this (without '()')

```js
<CheckerBoardTile @OnTileClicked="TileClicked('Tile1')" />
```

As a side note, if you wanted to emit a value, and then to handle it, you would write it this way.

```js
emit("myEvent", 123);
```

```js
<MyComponent @myEvent="(n) => count += n" />
```

or if your event handler is a method, the value would be passed in the first parameter of that method.

```js
<MyComponent @myEvent="myHandler" />
```

```js
function myHandler(n) {
    ...
}
```

References:

- https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html